# My Microphone goes back to listening after i go to another function

Tags: python

Whenever i run this code, and tell start the function "google", it goes back to another function. i have tried to do this for a few days now, and still no luck. any help would be appreciated:)

```
import webbrowser
import string
import time
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
engine = pyttsx3.init()
r = sr.Recognizer()

def Listen():
    with sr.Microphone() as sourceL:
        print("Listening...")
        Open = r.listen(sourceL, phrase_time_limit=2)
    try:
        if "Nova" in r.recognize_google(Open):
            print("Nova Recieved...")
            Command()
        else:
            Listen()
    except:
        Listen()

def Google():
    print("what would you like me to search for you? ")
    engine.say("what would you like me to search for you? ")
    engine.runAndWait()
    with sr.Microphone as source:
        Search = r.listen(source)
        Search = r.recognize(Search)
```

The code will go back to Listen() at `with sr.Mirophone as source`
This is how I am calling google()...

```
def Command():
    print("You called me?")
    engine.say("you called me? ")
    engine.runAndWait()
    Cr = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening For Command...")
        CommandToDo = Cr.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=2)
        print("...")
    if "YouTube" in Cr.recognize_google(CommandToDo):
        YouTube()

    elif "Google" in Cr.recognize_google(CommandToDo):
        Google()

    else:
        print("Command not recognized>> " + r.recognize_google(CommandToDo))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How are you calling `Google()` function ?

Comment: Codes been added @SoumendraKumarSahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function argument `phrase_time_limit` you need to specify while calling the `listen` method inside `Google` function.
`phrase_time_limit` represents the wait time of the program, for how many seconds it will wait for the user to give input. Here it will wait for 2 seconds. If you do not give any time limit it will wait indefinitely.

From the source code documentation:

> The `phrase_time_limit` parameter is the maximum number of seconds
>   that this will allow a phrase to continue before stopping and
>   returning the part of the phrase processed before the time limit was
>   reached. The resulting audio will be the phrase cut off at the time
>   limit. If `phrase_timeout` is `None`, there will be no phrase time
>   limit.

To clarify on the `timeout` argument

> The `timeout` parameter is the maximum number of seconds that this
>   will wait for a phrase to start before giving up and throwing an
>   `speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError` exception. If `timeout` is
>   `None`, there will be no wait timeout.

For more details check [the source code.](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py)

```
def Google():
    print("what would you like me to search for you? ")
    engine.say("what would you like me to search for you? ")
    engine.runAndWait()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        Search = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=2)  # <-- Here
        Search = r.recognize_google(Search)
        print(Search)
```

After this change, it is working for me.
Check it is
`with sr.Microphone() as source:` not
`with sr.Microphone as source:`. You missed the braces.

Comment: It still goes back to listen() unfortunatly